# Adding Sorbet type signatures to attr_reader/attr_writer with multiple variables

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have an `attr_reader` that provides more than one variable, like so:

```rb
attr_reader :user, :series
```

I want to add a type signature to it, but Sorbet doesn't support multiple return types,

```rb
sig { returns(User, Series) }
attr_reader :user, :series
```

Is the only option to split them up like so?:

```rb
sig { returns(User) }
attr_reader :user
sig { returns(Series) }
attr_reader :series
```

Comment: I think you have no other choice than splitting. It'll also be a bit better to know which attribute return what kind of value because list of type & list of attribute aren't always  perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only option is to split up your attribute declarations, just like how you would have done if you were defining separate getter/setter methods for them, unless all your attributes are of the same type.

The reason for this is that Sorbet, in the DSL phase of its operation, actually uses the `sig` on an `attr_reader`/`attr_writer`/`attr_accessor` declaration to define the `sig` on the synthetic methods that are produced by those declarations. Thus, a single getter for `attr_reader`, a single setter for `attr_writer` and a getter/setter pair for `attr_accessor` are generated synthetically and the `sig`s are applied to them.

As a result of this, [this would be valid](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(String)%20%7D%0A%20%20attr_reader%20%3Asome_string_attr%2C%20%3Aother_string_attr%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20main%0A%20%20T.reveal_type(A.new.some_string_attr)%0A%20%20T.reveal_type(A.new.other_string_attr)%0Aend):

```
sig { returns(String) }
attr_reader :some_string_attr, :other_string_attr
```

but this would not be:

```
sig { returns(String, User) }
attr_reader :some_string_attr, :some_user_attr
```